# How do I use dask distributed?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to use Dask by looking at the code examples and documentation, and have trouble understanding how it works. As suggested in the document, I am trying to use the distributed scheduler (I also plan to deploy my code on an HPC).

The first simple thing I tried was this:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.bag as db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client(n_workers=2)

print("hello world")
```

The `hello world` got printed thrice, which I think is because of the workers. I was assuming that unless compute is called, the workers are not started.
I can move my print statement to a function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client(n_workers=2)

def print_func():
    print("hello world")
```

But, how do I make sure that only one worker executes this function? (In MPI, I can do this by using `rank == 0`; I did not find anything similar to `MPI_Comm_rank()` which can tell me the worker number or id in Dask).

I went further and started using an example provided in Dask:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.bag as db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()

def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

b = db.from_sequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
c = b.filter(is_even).map(lambda x: x ** 2)
print(c.compute())
```

But this shows up an error: `An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase`. I was assuming that the `dask.bag` would split up the compute work automatically.
My apologies for a lengthy post, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around Dask (I am used to MPI and OpenMP programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, how do I make sure that only one worker executes this function? (In MPI, I can do this by using `rank == 0`; I did not find anything similar to `MPI_Comm_rank()` which can tell me the worker number or id in Dask).

This is effectively what the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is checking. That condition is true when your script is run directly; it's *not* true when it's imported as a module by the workers. Any code that you put outside of this block is run by every worker when it starts up; this should be limited to function definitions and necessary global setup. All of the code that actually *does work* needs to be in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, or inside functions which are only called from inside that block.

Comment: Nicely phrased answer

Comment: Thank you. So, I did move the dask bag computation inside a function, and call the function from main. But, is there a way to print worker_id or some kind of id that can tell me which worker worked on what piece of the data?